# Google GKE Load Balancer firewall need to block ping

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I need to lock down access to service running in Google Cloud Kubernetes. What I can do is use "loadBalancerSourceRanges" in service deployment with TCP load balancer to restrict networks that can access service say on port 443.

What I don't seem to be able to do is lock down ICMP traffic from internet hitting load balancer. This is security compliance requirement I have.

Google documentation and bug tracker seem to indicate that this is not possible. Am I correct and what is best alternative?

Answer (score 1):

If you go to VPC Network -> Firewall Rules -> Create firewall rule and select the targets as "All instances in the network" and block all ICMP requests you may be able to accomplish this (not tested).

Comment: This will block icmp to kubernetes nodes itself, not the load balancer. Looks like it sits outside and there is not much to do about it for now.