# Block ICMP trafic on kubernetes cluster GCP

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

Hi everyone I need to block ICMP protocol in my kubernetes cluster in GCP, but there is no way to do that. Someone could helpme

Comment: Hi Ruben! While the question is clear, may worth to add more information about your cluster. Is this a managed Kubernetes (GKE, AKS, EKS)? What version? Are you using ISTIO or any other service mesh? What CNI are you using? From where do you want to block ICMP protocol; from POD to POD or POD to VM or VM to POD or VM to VM (VM = K8s node)?  Whit more context we will be able to address all your concerns.

Comment: GKE, 1.17.17-gke.3700, No Service Mesh, GKE Defaul CNI. This is external ICMP connectivity while implementing a Load Balancer Service using GKE built-in feature, that is TCP Load Balancing. Thanks men

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google GKE Load Balancer firewall need to block ping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55705877/google-gke-load-balancer-firewall-need-to-block-ping)

Answer (score 0):

GKE creates firewall rules automatically when creating the following resources:

GKE clusters, GKE Services, GKE Ingresses

Below firewall rules are automatically created for clusters.

gke-[cluster-name]-[cluster-hash]-master (Only for private clusters), gke-[cluster-name]-[cluster-hash]-ssh (Only for public clusters), gke-[cluster-name]-[cluster-hash]-vms, gke-[cluster-name]-[cluster-hash]-all.

To block ICMP protocol for cluster, Goto Console->VPC network->Firewall->Select your cluster related firewall rules which are allowing ICMP. Click on **Edit** and go to **protocols and ports**. Under **Specified protocols and ports**, Deselect other protocols or delete icmp from the list of other protocols.

You can also create custom firewall rules with high priority than automatically created firewall rules. Configuration data of custom firewall rules should be same as automatically created firewall rules except priority.

First method is easy compared to the second one.